# Scrapy Splash get JavaScript response "Required argument is missing: url". Also call deprecated function to_native_str

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, docker-desktop, scrapy-splash

By trying to scrap the results from [the website](https://www.olg.ca/en/lottery/play-pick-2/past-results.html), I found the desired data in html labels are generated by a JavaScript. Web development tool shows the script address is probably [this](https://www.olg.ca/etc.clientlibs/olg-web/clientlibs/clientlib-vuejs.min.1.908.0.js). Looks like dynamic data fetching is mandatory. This is my code:

```
import scrapy as scrapy
from scrapy import crawler
import scrapy_splash

class TheSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Test'
    headers = {
        "X-Crawlera-Profile": "desktop", "X-Crawlera-Cookies": "disable",
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36 Edg/104.0.1293.63',
    }
    payload = {'as_epq': 'James Clark', 'tbs': 'cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/2015,cd_max:01/01/2015', 'tbm': 'nws'}
    root_url = 'https://www.olg.ca/en/lottery/play-pick-2/past-results.html'
    first_data_url = 'https://www.olg.ca/etc.clientlibs/olg-web/clientlibs/clientlib-vuejs.min.1.908.0.js'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.root_url, callback=self.parse, headers=self.headers,
                             meta={'splash': {'endpoint': 'render.html', 'args': {'wait': 0.5}}},
                             dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        print(2)
        yield scrapy_splash.SplashRequest(callback=self.first_data_response, headers=self.headers,
                                          args={'url': self.first_data_url, 'wait': 1.5, 'http_method': 'POST'},
                                          endpoint='render.html', dont_filter=True)

    def first_data_response(self, response):
        html_file = open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\htmlview.html", 'w', encoding="utf-8")
        html_file.write(response.body.decode("utf-8"))
        html_file.close()
        print('1')

process = crawler.CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(TheSpider)
process.start()
```

Header's user-agent settings are same to my browser. I use docker desktop to work with splash. Log shows there is nothing in the '**args**'. Here is part of the log:

```
2022-08-25 19:01:52.122094 [events] {"path": "/render.html", "rendertime": 0.03642439842224121, "maxrss": 540272, "load": [0.08, 0.18, 0.2], "fds": 53, "active": 0, "qsize": 0, "_id": 140124862624992, "method": "GET", "timestamp": 1661454112, "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36 Edg/104.0.1293.63", "args": {}, "status_code": 400, "client_ip": "172.17.0.1", "error": {"error": 400, "type": "BadOption", "description": "Incorrect HTTP API arguments", "info": {"type": "argument_required", "argument": "url", "description": "Required argument is missing: url"}}}
2022-08-25 19:01:52.423903 [-] "172.17.0.1" - - [25/Aug/2022:19:01:50 +0000] "GET /render.html HTTP/1.1" 400 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36 Edg/104.0.1293.63"
2022-08-25 19:11:40.559167 [events] {"path": "/render.html", "rendertime": 0.07086420059204102, "maxrss": 540272, "load": [0.22, 0.13, 0.15], "fds": 53, "active": 0, "qsize": 0, "_id": 140124862624992, "method": "GET", "timestamp": 1661454700, "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36 Edg/104.0.1293.63", "args": {}, "status_code": 400, "client_ip": "172.17.0.1", "error": {"error": 400, "type": "BadOption", "description": "Incorrect HTTP API arguments", "info": {"type": "argument_required", "argument": "url", "description": "Required argument is missing: url"}}}
2022-08-25 19:11:40.648981 [-] "172.17.0.1" - - [25/Aug/2022:19:11:40 +0000] "GET /render.html HTTP/1.1" 400 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36 Edg/104.0.1293.63"
```

This is all code added to **defualt_settings.py**, at end of the file:

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1.25
```

Server response 400. How to properly send the URL by `SplashRequest`? Is it because of the warning of calling to deprecated function `to_native_str`? Thanks for your help.

```
2022-08-25 15:00:32 [py.warnings] WARNING: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\scrapy_splash\request.py:42: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function to_native_str. Use to_unicode instead.
  url = to_native_str(url)

2022-08-25 15:00:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.olg.ca/etc.clientlibs/olg-web/clientlibs/clientlib-vuejs.min.1.908.0.js via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
```

Comment: https://gateway.wma.bedegaming.com/feeds/past-winning-numbers?game=pick2&startDate=2022-08-01&endDate=2022-08-26 - I guess you can send a request and get the data here. And if yes, no need Splash.

Comment: @Serhii Tried. Return 401. How did you get this link? Maybe it is the right address but need more work.

Comment: Network, Open DevTools by pressing Control+Shift+J or Command+Option+J (Mac)